# Replace Substrings In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I want to change substrings in excel based on a pre-defined value stored in a table.

How can I do that in Excel 2019 without VBA?

**Example:**

table1

| KEY | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | ABCDEFGHIJ |
| 02 | KHAZENCKAL |
| 03 | PZTEWRNBGM |

now I have another table with the stored values to be used.

table2

| OLD VALUE | NEW VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | AYY |
| B | BEE |
| C | CEE |
| D | DEE |
| E | EEE |
| F | FEE |

..and so forth

now I want to add a new column to table1 that contains that new values.

table1 (updated)

| KEY | TEXT | NEW TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | ABCDEFGHIJ | AYYBEECEEDEEEEEEFFGEEAYHEYEJAY |
| 02 | KHAZENCKAL | KAYAYHAYYZEEEEEENNCEEKAYAYYELL |
| 03 | PZTEWRNBGM | PEEZEETEEEEEWYUAREENNBEEGEEEMM |

How can I achieve that?

Appreciate the help.

edit1: formula not working
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried out =substitute?

Comment: One way : `=TEXTJOIN("",1,IFNA(VLOOKUP(MID(B2,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(B2))),1),$F$2:$G$7,2,0),""))`

Comment: i used: SUBSTITUTE(TABLE1[TEXT],TABLE2[OLD VALUE],TABLE2[NEW VALUE] and it doesn't work. am I missing something here?

Comment: could you please help me understand what is $ZZ$1? thanks

Comment: `$ZZ$1` refers to column `ZZ` and `1` means the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could try using `TEXTJOIN()` & `VLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN("",1,
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 MID([@TEXT],
 ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(B2))),1),Table2,2,0),""))
```

---

Or other way which is not suggestive to use is `INDIRECT()` function to create the sequence:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",1,
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 MID([@TEXT],
 ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2))),1),Table2,2,0),""))
```

---

Comment: Thank you, but with me it is giving a different result: 
|KEY|TEXT|Column1|
|--|--|--|
|1|ABCDEFGHIJ|AYY|
|2|KHAZENCKAL| |
|3|PZTEWRNBGM| |
why?

Comment: @ouboma like for example?

Comment: the first entry in column1 is AYY and the rest are blank

Comment: It is still working on my end, I am not sure how you say its not working. Because I have clearly shown in the screenshot. Also since you are using MS2019, you would need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode.

Comment: explain to me like i'm 5 please: why are you using row Z? what's in there?

Comment: @ouboma why cant you show me where it is not working for you? Also have you tried to evaluate that part? `ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(B2)))` there is nothing `Z` col, but it creates a sequence to split the strings in cell `B2` to split by 1 character each by row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257060/discussion-between-ouboma-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).